# Why I get wrong forecast values python-weka wrapper

Tags: python, wrapper, weka, forecast

I would like to predict data using the python-weka-wrapper in Jupyter Notebook, however, I just get the error but not the given prediction. This is a sample of my data:

```
@relation data_new3

@attribute pos_x numeric
@attribute pos_y numeric
@attribute angle numeric
@attribute vel numeric
@attribute vel_x numeric
@attribute vel_y numeric

@data
414049364,21773560,75.06043,16.775027,15.827037,-5.559355
414049656,21773926,43.232657,4.452031,3.258594,-3.033504
414049938,21774287,43.836066,4.347145,4.300749,-0.633426
414050204,21774638,44.704315,4.157368,3.119995,2.747606
```

When I run this data on Weka using the Forecast tab (selecting pos_x and pos_y as variables to predict) y get a valid prediction (linear regression). However, when I'm trying to build it on python to automatize the process, the results are far from expected.

This is my current code:

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
import weka.core.converters as conv
from weka.classifiers import Evaluation, Classifier
from weka.core.classes import Random
import weka.plot.classifiers as plcls
df = conv.load_any_file("data_new3.arff")
df.class_is_last()

cls = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression", options=["-C","-S","1"])
evl = Evaluation(df)
evl.crossvalidate_model(cls, df, 10, Random(1))
plcls.plot_classifier_errors(evl.predictions, absolute=False, wait=True)
```

I would like to get n number of predictions (forecast).
Below the result of the above code. However, I would like data not error.

evl.predictions content:

```
[NUM: 2.341519980578598 -0.46169578717854165 1.0,
 NUM: 0.0324593108656498 -1.250148004408402 1.0,
 NUM: 1.0894596695042125 -0.19638227888390247 1.0,
 NUM: 2.2415137801101532 0.21523000008892268 1.0,
 NUM: 0.8403094260947848 1.4159336571192398 1.0,
 NUM: -0.6246802557143522 0.02694804349266633 1.0,
 NUM: -1.1291083174467442 -0.9771784825188661 1.0,
 NUM: 1.9865123314290711 0.0020180962164886296 1.0,
 NUM: -1.4171054579203468 -0.1185322656565404 1.0,
 NUM: 1.701392413210111 -0.31173498990392545 1.0,
 NUM: 0.9142204697441169 -0.46289838829034125 1.0,
 NUM: 2.2371544887471027 0.26863408847202663 1.0,
 NUM: 1.0104945457853498 0.08266907560209802 1.0,
 NUM: -2.1844092184524277 0.2537549599419435 1.0,
 NUM: -1.64486932964462 -0.0757717380165559 1.0,
 NUM: -0.8833185855520697 0.272053514894651 1.0,
 NUM: 2.023258402624002 0.20075652151535905 1.0,
 NUM: -0.09766261800428815 -0.13010619249325828 1.0,
 NUM: 0.008614470166021827 -2.0206928075313044 1.0,
 NUM: -0.3746145438554381 0.2627094869476423 1.0,
 NUM: 0.321292162562831 -0.39300510611246864 1.0,
 NUM: -0.8603272578575111 -0.24401632088301994 1.0,
 NUM: 1.2917808082313293 0.27398191955035145 1.0,
 NUM: 2.5069928462982736 -0.28666784299093706 1.0,
 NUM: 0.5342954034915244 0.023908866474812385 1.0,
 NUM: -0.8199944215138957 -0.35662294870599 1.0,
 NUM: 1.5190967129296846 -0.494692957136067 1.0,
 NUM: 2.1750768892884005 0.17687020938865317 1.0,
 NUM: -1.3129196874730458 -0.4337196896722162 1.0,
 NUM: 0.9085960948511023 -1.0273595147173182 1.0,
 NUM: -1.790840080776049 -0.7976173866791214 1.0,
 NUM: 0.6226362259069361 0.8034413426921674 1.0,
 NUM: -1.6641718286913476 0.1441503225123597 1.0,
 NUM: 0.9671958169480396 0.4460301975123002 1.0,
 NUM: -0.0762479157090975 -0.014214109052772983 1.0,
 NUM: 0.1274295194870555 -0.7136733953120711 1.0,
```

What I'm doing wrong? I cannot find the right function in https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html

Answer (score 0):

Forecasting (i.e., predicting the next point in a timeseries) is different from a single point prediction. The former is available through Weka's [timeseriesForecasting](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/timeseriesForecasting/) package and the *Forecast* tab in the Weka Explorer. The latter is what classifiers normally do and is available through the *Classify* tab in the Weka Explorer.

The *Forecast* tab wraps the actual base classifier in a `WekaForecaster` instance (which is not a classifier but a forecaster!) and also transforms the data using the `TSLagMaker` filter internally.

Up till now, the [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) library had no support for forecasting.
With the new release [0.2.0](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3/releases/tag/v0.2.0) a new module got introduced: `weka.timeseries`. This new module wraps the essential classes of the `timeseriesForecasting` package.

Some pointers:

- [API documentation](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html#module-weka.timeseries)
- code examples ([1](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html#timeseries), [2](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/api.html#timeseries), [3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/blob/master/src/wekaexamples/timeseries/timeseries.py))